# Where is the framebuffer?

Tags: macos, unix

I am looking for the macOS location of Linux's `/dev/fb0` in order to adapt the code in [this Unix stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192206/is-it-possible-to-access-to-the-framebuffer-in-order-to-put-a-pixel-on-the-scree) and [this article](http://seenaburns.com/2018/04/04/writing-to-the-framebuffer/) to macOS. I am on Sierra if that is relevant.

Comment: The linked answer is in relation to X-Windows.  macOS uses Quartz (Metal in Mojave).  See:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics

Comment: @Allan Okay, so https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services seems like the page I'm interested in? I'm not sure if this is within the scope of this site but I'm pretty lost. Would you mind writing an example similar to the one in the linked question?

Comment: @Allan That appears to be emulating a framebuffer, not using the real one. If it matters, im trying to recreate the old Crabs virus for Mac. (I can't find a link for reference, but pretty much it's a gray square that moves around the screen leaving a trail, and it works by writing directly to the framebuffer.)

Comment: Did you have any luck so far?